# Worklight WAR File Error

Tags: java, ant, db2, ibm-mobilefirst, war

I am working with Worklight 6.2 and I am using ANT tasks to install the console and I am getting this error:

> worklght:/opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/configuration-samples #
>   ant -f configure-was-db2.xml install Buildfile: configure-was-db2.xml
>
> install: [configureapplicationserver] Logging output of task
>    to file
>   /root/.worklight/configuration-logs/configureApplicationServer_2015_01_30_13_46_11.log
>   [configureapplicationserver] ** Creating migrated war file
>   [configureapplicationserver] Jan 30, 2015 1:46:13 PM
>   com.worklight.ant.migration.MigrationTask MigrationTask.execute
>   [configureapplicationserver] SEVERE: FWLST2018E: The project WAR file
>   could not be migrated from version older than 5.0.6 to version
>   6.2.0.00.20140613-0730 because this migration path is not supported. Use a project WAR file of version 5.0.6 or later, and restart the
>   migration process.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   /opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/configuration-samples/configure-was-db2.xml:167:
>   FWLST2018E: The project WAR file could not be migrated from version
>   older than 5.0.6 to version 6.2.0.00.20140613-0730 because this
>   migration path is not supported. Use a project WAR file of version
>   5.0.6 or later, and restart the migration process.

new fresh install question

I did a fresh install and I am going to rerun the ant tasks. I am using configure liberty db2. But why is it asking me for the app server?  Is that referring to my Lliberty directory?  in configure-liberty-db2 its asking me:

Comment: Are you in fact trying to migrating a 5.0.5 project to 6.2?

Comment: If yes, you must first migrate the project to 5.0.6 and the migrate that project to 6.2

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am just trying to deploy the work light admin console so I may upload my adapters. The only worklightconsole.war file is already on the server. I have the latest WL 6.2 installed. I don't see how the latest version of worklight would have an old war file. Any idea on how to migrate? I can't find any good guides? Or is there a new file?

Comment: Again, is this a new project you are working on or an existing one? The error message seems very clear about it, so need to make sure what is your current project.

Comment: This is a current project that I am working on. I am using the default worklightadmin.war so I may deploy the console. On my console I am getting a runtime error. The war file came after I installed it on my server.

Comment: This is not what I am asking you... I am asking, did you create a new project in worklight 6.2, or are you using an old project?

Comment: My liberty profile was deploy when I started the server. I didn't use ANT tasks to create my server

Comment: Sorry for not understanding. I didn't create any project. I simply took whatever files that were in Worklight 6.2

Comment: Hi Idan. I got the proper file but now I am getting: IBM Worklight Console
Welcome, admin Logout About
Available runtime environments
Select the Worklight runtime environment to manage.

Server error. Contact the server administrator.

Comment: I uninstalled my previous adminstall and reinstalled it and when I logon after that it says no runtime found which make sense becuase I didn't install it yet. It is after I install the runtime is where it seems there are problems

Comment: what's in the messages.log file?

Comment: When I try to hit worklightadmin I get Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [authenticationFilter]: Could not find required filter class - com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.class

Comment: What's in the messages.log? ... I suspect you are not fully following the deployment instructions. I would also verify that you are using the latest available 6.2 version from IBM Fix Central. Edit: 6.2.0.00.20140613 is very very very old. Update.

Comment: [WARNING ] CWWKG0011W: The configuration validation did not succeed. Found conflicting settings for worklightadmin instance of application configuration.
  Property location has conflicting values:
    Value worklightadmin.war is set in file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml.
    Value demo_v62.war is set in file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml.
  Property location will be set to demo_v62.war.

Comment: Great. Both update to the latest version as well as provide your server.xml (edit the question with a link to download the file from somewhere)

Comment: I can't upgrade to the latest and greatest. I don't have access to it. But I will upload the server XML file

Comment: I you are an IBM customer, you should be able to download all required artifacts.

Comment: IBM BP. I uploaded the server XML. Can you please take a look? The worklight war file is calle demo_v62.war  -- I will work on getting the latest

Comment: Can't spot the error myself; I'll see if the server team can help.

Comment: Thank you Idan. Appreciate your help

Comment: I am also going to upload my logs that I pulled

Answer (score 0):

According with the content of your server.xml file, your runtime war file has the same name and the same context root than the admin services : worklightadmin. All the applications deployed in a server must have their own unique context root.

Comment: Thanks for help all. I had a quick question. I posted it in my question box